# Indian grouping of thousand, lakhs and crores separator jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using opencart 2.3 version and displaying price for all products.
Below is my price format,
₹120,000
₹20,000
But I want 120,000 in indian currency format like => 1,20,00.

Below is my html,

```
<span class="orgprice">₹120,000</span>
```

I want to separate above text to 1,20,00 how to ahieve this on load of the page.

Comment: See this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#108532

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct Indian format? As far as I remember it's 3 in the last group and 2 in others, f. ex. `1,20,000`